# Lognormal model: reporting median or geometric mean

Tags: regression, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, lognormal-distribution, reporting

**I have a bayesian lognormal model as follows ([brms package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/index.html)):**

```
m = brm(y ~ 1, data = df, family = lognormal)
```

Model was run with default priors.

**This is model's posterior samples on lognormal scale**

```
posterior_samples(m)
```

[image]

**Is exponentiated b_Intercept the median or geometric mean of y variable?**

I have seen that some websites say that this is a geometric mean, some refer to this as a median. Or if this is something different, could you please provide a formula for calculating geometric mean or median from this posterior?

```
posterior_samples(m) %>% 
mutate(transformed = exp(b_Intercept)) %>% 
posterior_summary() %>% as.data.frame()
```

[image]

**Crude median, mean and geometric mean of Y for comparison**

[image]
Crude geometric mean was calculated as follows: exp(mean(log(df$y)))

**Data used**

```
set.seed(0)
pi <- 0
mu_log <- 2
sigma_log <- 0.99
N = 1000
y = (1 - rbinom(N, 1, prob = pi)) * rlnorm(N, mu_log, sigma_log)
df = data.frame(y=y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky.  The link function for brms' `lognormal` is the identity link by default.  This means that the underlying Stan model codes the likelihood as `mu = Intercept; target += lognormal_lpdf(Y | mu, sigma);`, which is leads to an estimate of the median on the log scale. Thus, `exp(b_Intercept)` should me the median.  This is supported by a small example:

```
set.seed(0)
N = 10000
y = rlnorm(N, 0.5, 0.5)

d = tibble(y)


model = brm(y~1, family = lognormal(), data = d)


median(y)
>>>1.655619

model %>% 
  spread_draws(b_Intercept) %>% 
  mutate(b_Intercept = exp(b_Intercept)) %>% 
  mean_qi


# A tibble: 1 x 6
  b_Intercept .lower .upper .width .point .interval
        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    
1        1.65   1.63   1.67   0.95 mean   qi
```

As for the difference between geometric mean and median, [it seems that the geometric mean for the lognormal is $\exp(\mu)$ which is the median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Properties). The difference between your estimate and your model's estimate could be due to regularization by the priors, but I can't be sure  Are you willing to post the data?

Comment: Thank you so much Demetri! I used default priors and added the data used. Updated the original post accordingly.

Comment: @st4co4 Yes, `exp(b_Intercept)` in the model you've provided is an estimate of the median.  The median of your distribution would be `exp(2) = 7.38...`.  This seems to be the same as the geometric mean.  Its all making sense now since the `mean(log(y))` is an estimate of mu, so your geometric mean calculation is an estimate of `exp(mu)` i.e. the median.

Comment: Thank you so much! I own you many beers now!